# Body Blocking Top Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, navigation, css

I'm using SharePoint 2010.  I updated HTML in a copy of the v4 master, linked in a CSS for styling, and my mega menu isn't showing correctly.  It displays perfectly, except anything on the page hides the mega menu content.

[image: Example]

Any guidance would be much appreciated.  I'm pretty much a novice at this, but our company is in need of having a mega menu.

Comment: maybe the div you want to put on the top of everything doesnt' have z-index property set to a high number. Give it a try. If you don't know what z-index is google it because there are many samples. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your custom css and add the following:

.mdd-topmenu-item { z-index: auto;}

The above property is working fine for us. Hope this helps.